# Control Save shortcut in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

I had an audio file in web url , while pressing control+S key an dialogue box open to save file.
I need to simulate same using selenium in headless mode.
I tried actionchain but no sucess.

Answer (score 0):

In java we can use Robot API

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S)
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S)
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
```

Not very sure whether we can do the similar thing in python

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 's')
```